# Getting NoSuchMethodError while executing the spark job in CDP

Tags: cloudera-cdp

I am getting the below error while executing the spark job in Cloudera as I have placed a jar file in hdfs and trying to initiate the sparkjob through the Oozie client and getting the below error.

Failing Oozie Launcher, org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()Lorg/spark_project/guava/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()Lorg/spark_project/guava/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService;
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.(ThreadUtils.scala:37)
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.(ThreadUtils.scala)
at org.apache.spark.status.ElementTrackingStore.(ElementTrackingStore.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.status.AppStatusStore$.createLiveStore(AppStatusStore.scala:556)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:420)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
at com.macys.stella.utils.SparkUtils.configureContext(SparkUtils.java:33)
at com.macys.stella.ReindexJob.run(ReindexJob.java:66)
at com.macys.stella.ReindexJob.main(ReindexJob.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.runSpark(SparkMain.java:183)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.run(SparkMain.java:90)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:107)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.main(SparkMain.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.runActionMain(LauncherAM.java:417)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.access$400(LauncherAM.java:55)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM$2.run(LauncherAM.java:232)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1898)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.run(LauncherAM.java:226)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM$1.run(LauncherAM.java:156)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1898)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.main(LauncherAM.java:144)
Oozie Launcher, uploading action data to HDFS sequence file: hdfs://jd05-stars-nn/user/fsgapp/oozie-oozi/0000022-240312074832481-oozie-oozi-W/spark-node--spark/action-data.seq

Even I have excluded the versions from the original jar still i am facing that issue as Oozie libraries is having the spark-network-common jar in it lib path with the same version i build the jar and running the application getting the above runtime error.

Any suggestions please.

I have tried by excluding the spark-network-common under spark-core_2.11 jar still the issue is not resolved.